# How to compute the sum of some variables in Stata?

Tags: variables, sum, stata

I have 48 variables in my dataset: first 12 concern year 2000, second 12 year 2001, third 12 year 2002 and fourth 12 year 2003.
Each single variable contains the values in such a way:

| ID | var1 | var2 | var3 | ... | var12 | ... | var48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | ... | 0 |
| yy | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 9 | ... | 0 |
| zz | 3 | 2 | 1 | ... | 0 | ... | 0 |

Now, I want to collect the sum of the values of the first 12 variables in another one called, say, "tot_2000" which should contain just one number (in this example it is 18).
Then, I must repeat this passage for the 3 remaining years, thus having 4 variables ("tot_2000", "tot_2001", "tot2002", "tot2003") to be plotted in an histogram.

What I'm looking for is such a variable:

| tot_2000 |
| --- |
| 18 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORIGINAL QUESTION, addressed by @TheIceBear and myself.

I have a dataset that contains, say, 12 variables with values 0,1,2.... like this, for example:

| ID | var1 | var2 | var3 | ... | var12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xx | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| yy | 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 9 |
| zz | 3 | 2 | 1 | ... | 0 |

and I want to create a variable that is just the sum of all the values (18 in this case), like:

**tot_var**
18

What is the command?

FIRST ANSWER FROM ME

Here is another way to do it, as indicated in a comment on the first answer by @TheIceBear.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str2 ID byte(var1 var2 var3 var4)
"xx" 0 0 1 1
"yy" 1 0 0 9
"zz" 3 2 1 0
end

mata : total = sum(st_data(., "var1 var2 var3 var4")) 

mata : st_numscalar("total", total)

di scalar(total)
18
```

The two Mata commands could be telescoped.

SECOND ANSWER

A quite different question is emerging slowly from comments and edits. The question is still unfocused, but here is an attempt to sharpen it up.

You have monthly data for various identifiers. You want to see bar charts (not histograms) with annual totals.

The data structure or layout you have is a poor fit for handling such data in Stata. You have a so-called wide layout but a long layout is greatly preferable. Then your totals can be put in a variable for graphing.

```
* fake dataset 
clear
set obs 3 
gen id = word("xx yy zz", _n)

forval j = 1/48 { 
    gen var`j' = _n * `j'
}

* you start here 
reshape long var, i(id) j(time)
gen mdate = ym(1999, 12) + time 
format mdate %tm 
gen year = year(dofm(mdate))

* not clear that you want this, but it could be useful 
egen total = total(var), by(id year)
twoway bar total year, by(id) xla(2000/2003) name(G1, replace)

* this seems to be what you are asking for 
egen TOTAL = total(var), by(year)
twoway bar TOTAL year, base(0) xla(2000/2003) name(G2, replace)
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I clearly made a mistake when explaining my issue; I am very sorry! I wrote what I need in one of the last comments on the first answer.

Comment: The version of your question in your latest comment cannot be inferred from the original text.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better, but I'll try anyways.
48 variables: first 12 concern year 2000, second 12 year 2001, third 12 year 2002 and fourth 12 year 2003.
Each single variable contains the values in the way I showed in the question.
Now, I want to collect the sum of the values of the first 12 variables in another one called, say, "tot_2000" which should contain just one number (in the example was 18).
Then, I must repeat this passage for the 3 remaining years, having then 4 variables ("tot_2000", "tot_2001", "tot2002", "tot2003") to be plotted in an histogram.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for how to do it in two steps:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str2 ID byte(var1 var2 var3 var4)
"xx" 0 0 1 1
"yy" 1 0 0 9
"zz" 3 2 1 0
end

egen row_sum = rowtotal(var*) //Sum each row into a var
egen tot_var = sum(row_sum ) //Sum the row_sum var

* Get the value of the first observation and store in a local macro
local total = tot_var[1]
display `total'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this way too and Stata keeps giving me a variable which contains the sum (18) repeated for every ID! Hence 18 for "xx", 18 for "yy" and so on!

Comment: Yes, that's what you asked for. Maybe not what you meant, but what your question asks for. Perhaps provide example data where you manually indicate your desired results.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I explained it in the wrong way. I meant that I want a variable that contains just one number and that number should be the sum of all the values inside the twelve variables.

Comment: That would not be a variable in Stata’s sense. You could use Mata to get a scalar.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is a fair mistake to call this a variable as in most other programming languages that would be correct. Perhaps you are coming from Python. A variable in Stata is only a column in a dataset. What you are asking for is perhaps suitable for a macro. If a macro is most suitable depends on what you want to do with this number next. I have updated my example with how to store the results in a local macro.

Comment: Thank you both! But I really need that 18 to be stored into a variable in order to plot it into an histogram :(

Comment: All variables in a dataset must have the same number of observations. Show how you, in a single dataset, want the `tot_var` variable to be included in the dataset with the rest of the variables you want to include in the histogram.

Comment: In my dataset I have 48 variables, theoretically divided into 4 years hence I have 12 variables that collect some data for one month of a single year, other 12 variables that catch data of another year and so on. My aim is to collect the sum of the values of each year (sum of the values of the first 12 variables) into a single variable and than, once I have the 4-year sum variables, I want to plot them in an histogram to see how things changed from a year to another.

Comment: This material should be added to the question. You’re new to SO, which is fine, but the question should be up front, not added belatedly.

Comment: You're right. I have updated everything.